# What architecture for a tool based application with Godot

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, godot

I'm currently developing an application that can create and export battle maps for my DnD (and other RPGs) groups. I use Godot as a foundation because it brings a lot of features that support this use case like sprite rendering, polygons, shaders, an amazing UI framework etc.

I have a scene tree that looks roughly as follows:

- Window

  - Menu

    - ...
  - ToolWindow

    - SelectionTool
    - Polygon Tool
    - ...
  - Canvas

    - ToolSpecificNodes

      - SpritePreview
    - MapRoot

      - Polygon1
      - Sprite1

Whenever another tool is selected I discard all nodes under "ToolSpecificNodes" and let the selected tool add it's own nodes. Every tool has a select() and deselect() lifecycle-method and a reference to canvas. Every tool also comes with a property window that it manages itself.

My question is how I would integrate the different tools in a way that allows them to be loosely coupled and exchangeable. The planned tools are "select tool", "polygon tool", "line tool", "sprite tool". I'm struggling especially with the "select tool" as it kind of relies on the other tools for handling stuff like polygon deformation, line deformation and sprite scaling.

Is there a well known architecture pattern that covers this use case? Or maybe an example project that shows this without too much added complexity? None-Godot solutions are also welcome as I should be able to apply them to my context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general,

- If you reference other classes (or nodes, in this case) directly, you have tightly coupled code.
- If you use dependency injection (or means for code to find each other, such as reflection, or a service locator), and interfaces (or use duck typing) you have loosely coupled code.
- If you use an infrastructure to pass messages between objects (i.e. signals), you have decoupled code.

---

Thus, if you want your tools to be **decoupled**, use signals.

When a tool is available, it connects to the whatever signals it needs. When the tools is no longer available it disconnects.

**Note**: freeing an object automatically disconnects it.

Then other code (e.g. where you handle input) can emit signals, without worrying which tool or tools ara available at the moment.

This, combined with the fact that an object can emit signals of other objects, would also allow for communication between tools. However, it does not allow a tool to communicate to one other particular tool specifically (such references from one tool to another would couple them).

**Addendum**: You can use a Signal Bus to decouple to code further, as I describe [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69969256/402022).

---

And if you want your tools to be **loosely coupled**, but not decoupled…

Wherever you need to, keep a reference to the current tool. So you can call into it. Changing the current tool is changing that reference.

**Addendum**: Perhaps you would benefit from a stack. Where the top of the stack is the current tool. So you can push tools on the stack when you select them. And pop them when you deselect them. Which returns the user to the tool they were previously using.

You, of course, don't want tools to have references to each other, but you want them to be able to find each other. A simple mechanism for this would be looking in the scene tree, and if the desired tool is not there, load it. So, let us put that logic into an [autoload (sigleton)](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/singletons_autoload.html). It will be our [service locator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern).

To do that, create a scene with only the root node. And add it as an autoload, with some name, let us say "ToolLocator". Give the root node a script, we need to add a method that will give us a reference to a tool:

```
func get_tool(name:String) -> Node:
    return null # TODO
```

It will check if it has the tool loaded. We will use the scene tree for that. And if it is loaded, return it:

```
func get_tool(name:String) -> Node:
    var result := get_node_or_null(name)
    if result != null:
        return result

    return null # TODO
```

Otherwise, it will attempt to load it. For that, it will attempt to construct a resource path from the name of the tool. And, of course, it has to keep it (in the scene tree) for future requests.

```
const tool_resource_root := "res://tools/"
const extension := ".tscn"

func get_tool(name:String) -> Node:
    var result := get_node_or_null(name)
    if result != null:
        return result

    var packed_scene := load(tool_resource_root + name + extension) as PackedScene
    if packed_scene != null:
        result = packed_scene.instance()
        result.name = name
        add_child(result)
        return result

    return null
```

*In this case, we are looking for the tool scenes at `"res://tools/"` and with the extension `".tscn"`.*

Being this an autoload, you can use it from any scene, like this:

```
var polygon_tool := ToolLocator.get_tool("polygon")
```

And yes, that would include the tool scenes. That is, tool scenes would be able to find each other like that. Thus, this is a way that they can communicate without hard-coding references or their type. In other words, they are loosely coupled.

**Note**: you need to handle the case when the tool is not available (`get_tool` returns null). Consider adding `push_error` at the end of `get_tool`, before returning null.

---

*You may also want to have a look at  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com, this question would be on topic there.*