# How to get a node in another scene godot?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am making a game with multiple scenes and need to have varibles that are get_node(node from another scene) and I don't know how to get nodes from another scene.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Don't know how to reference other scene into script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65660219/dont-know-how-to-reference-other-scene-into-script)

Comment: no it does not and for clarification I want to get a node from that scene.

Comment: The other scene might not be instanced. Might be instanced. And might be instanced multiple times. And those instances may or may not be in the scene tree. What is it you are actually trying to do?

Comment: var bullet = preload("res://Bullet.tscn")
func _ready():
        #var bulletnode = bullet.get_node("Bullet")
 #bulletnode.connect("a1", self, "a1")

#func a1():
 #create_planet()

this is trying to receve the signal a1

extends RigidBody2D
signal a1(value, other_value)

func _on_Area2D_area_entered(area):
 if area.is_in_group("planet"):
  self.queue_free()
  emit_signal("a1")
this emits the signal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to connect to signals from a node in another scene.

---

The direct approach would work:

```
const bullet := preload("res://Bullet.tscn")

func create_bullet() -> void:
    var instance := bullet.instance()
    instance.connect("hit", self, "method")
    get_parent().add_child(instance)
    # etc

func method() -> void:
    # whatever
    pass
```

However, this is not always convenient.

---

To decouple the code further, I suggest using a Signal Bus.

The insight is that object can emit signals of other objects. And thus, if you have a common object that everybody can refer to, you can put your signals there.

To have an object that everybody can refer to, create an [autoload (singleton)](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/singletons_autoload.html). You can call it `SignalBus`.

Have a script in autoload where you define signals. For example:

```
signal hit
```

Then where you need to emit the signal, do this:

```
SignalBus.emit_signal("hit")
```

And to connect to it where you need to receive it, do this:

```
func _ready() -> void:
    SignalBus.connect("hit", self, "method")

func method() -> void:
    # whatever
    pass
```

Since every scene can reference the autoload, any of them can emit and any of them can receive the signal. They don't need to know each other.

Comment: Yes! thank you I used the direct method the only issue i incounterd is that it creates a non moving bullet when i launch it. if you can help with that too that would be great.

Comment: @T-Rex that one would have to be done for every bullet as part of the code that shoots it. If the code that needs the signal is in the script that shoots the bullets, that is fine. But if it is elsewhere, it leads to further complications (the code that shoots the bullets would need to communicate with that elsewhere too). Thus, the signal bus (a.k.a event bus) is better, except for the simplest cases.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer by @Theraot for those using Godot 4, wherever you need to receive the "hit" signal...

```
func _ready():
    initialize_signals()

func initialize_signals():
    SignalBus.connect("hit", self.call("method"))
```